# Why do my windows occasionally stop taking keyboard input after alt-tab?

Tags: keyboard, window, vim

I have recently installed Ubuntu 16.04. Two different applications (Vim and Awesomenauts), on different occasions, have started completely ignoring keyboard input - though mouse input still works.

This goes away after opening a new instance of the program. I am not aware of the precise circumstances of it happening, as it's only happened twice, but I believe it may be just following <kbd>alt</kbd>-<kbd>tab</kbd> to switch windows.

What could I have done to cause this behaviour?

Comment: Similar question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11885979/mapping-alttab-in-vim

Comment: I don't think that is similar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out the shortcut <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>S</kbd> freezes keyboard input. This can be undone with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Q</kbd>.